# GAM model with 3 and 4 level factors produces errors

Tags: r, gam

I apologize in advance, for this very likely, very stupid question. But I am having trouble understanding the error messages I get, and likely the model I am using, as I am not able to correct the error.

As far as I understand, GAMs should be able to analyse predictor variables that are factors. I have tidal cycle (4 levels) and tidal phase (3 factors). And basically I want to know, if they have an effect on presence of cetaceans (presence/absence being the response variable).

I have the following code, which worked with sea surface temperature (SST)and tidal height (continuous variables):

```
gam.SST<-gam(presence~s(SST,k=4), 
        data=variables,
        family = binomial(link=logit))
```

Running this on the cycle or phase, I get the following error message:

```
Error in smooth.construct.tp.smooth.spec(object, dk$data, dk$knots) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(xx) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In Ops.factor(xx, shift[i]) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors
```

The sample size is fairly small, with only 93 observations.

Now I was wondering, if anybody could explain to me please, what I am doing wrong please? Any suggestion into the right direction would be appreciated.

Oh, and I already changed the k value to 3 and 2, as I read somewhere, that that might be causing issued due to the low number of levels. But the error doesn't change on '3', and an additional error appears, when I go down to '2':

```
3: In smooth.construct.tp.smooth.spec(object, dk$data, dk$knots) :
basis dimension, k, increased to minimum possible
```

Again, any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.
Regards,
Christina

Comment: You can include categorical variables in a GAM, but you can't smooth them.

Comment: I'd suggest something like `presence ~ s(SST,k=4) + tidal_model + tidal_phase`. If you think the shape of the `SST` response might vary considerably by one of your categorical variables, you can use, e.g., `s(SST, k = 4, b = tidal_model)`.

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems. One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg